# how to add and redraw a CALayer from a background task?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, calayer

- I have an UIView “myuiview”.
- I have some CALayers added to that view. In my sample its just one “calayer”
- In a background task I am creating a complex shape and add that to the calayer.
- In the mainthread I refresh the calayer and expect to see the new shape on the screen.

The new shape only appears after moving the screen and calling the CGAffineTransformTranslate(myuiview,x,y);

What am I doing wrong ?

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {

    var calayer:CALayer=CALayer();  
    myuiview.layer.addSublayer(calayer);
    myshape=createShape(); // takes long, thats why in the background.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        calayer.addSublayer(myshape)
        calayer.setNeedsDisplay(); // No update on the screen !!!!
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue because you manage layer hierarchy from non-main thread. Move related code inside dispatch main queue block and it should work. To deal with performance you can perform rendering in non-main thread in offline bitmap context, generate CGImage and provide it as content to layer in main thread